# How to avoid duplication when using 2 foreach php

Tags: php

Hello i have this code in `php` where i want 2 `arrays` to have their values put together, this is the code:

```
<?php
$values = [1,2,3];
$names = ['K', 'O', 'E'];
foreach($values as $value){
    foreach($names as $name){
        echo $value.$name;
    }
}
?>
```

What i get is:

```
1K1O1E2K2O2E3K3O3E
```

What i need is

```
1K2O3E
```

I am trying to understand that the second foreach executes more then the first array but cannot find the solution.

Comment: Will both arrays always be the same length?

Comment: yes they will be same length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the desired output of "1K2O3E", you can use the [**array_combine()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) function in PHP to combine the two arrays and then loop through the resulting array to create the desired output. Here's an example:

```
$values = [1, 2, 3];
$names = ['K', 'O', 'E'];

// combine the two arrays
$combined = array_combine($values, $names);

// initialize an empty string to store the output
$output = '';

// loop through the combined array and concatenate the values
foreach ($combined as $value => $name) {
    $output .= $value . $name;
}

// output the final result
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since both arrays are the same length, you can use a loop over the length of the first array, and use the index to concatenate both values:

```php
<?php
    $values = [1,2,3];
    $names = ['K', 'O', 'E'];
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++) {
        echo $values[$i] . $names[$i];
    }
```

```
1K2O3E
```

---

Based on your comment, you can use a single `foreach` with `=>` to get the index, then use that to get the other value from `names`.

```php
<?php
    $values = [1,2,3];
    $names = ['K', 'O', 'E'];
    
    foreach ($values as $i => $v) {
        echo $v . $names[$i];
    }
```

Comment: i know with for loop but im trying to see if its possible without one

Comment: is it possible without a for loop?

Comment: Please see my edit using `foreach`.